# How to Increase Accepted Header Size of the Ballerina Http Listener?

Tags: http-headers, ballerina, httplistener

I have encountered an issue where the Ballerina Http Listener returns a 431 error due to header size limitations. How can I increase the accepted header size?

Answer (score 1):

We can use the [RequestLimitConfigs](https://central.ballerina.io/ballerina/http/latest#RequestLimitConfigs) to overwrite the default header size. This is a part of the [http:ListenerConfiguration](https://central.ballerina.io/ballerina/http/latest#ListenerConfiguration).

Example :

```php
http:ListenerConfiguration serverEP = {
    requestLimits: {
        maxHeaderSize: <size-in-bytes>
    }
};
```